# How can I check if transform eulerAngles is at 0,0,0,?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateRandom : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Whilefun.FPEKit.FPEInteractionManagerScript.naviRotate == true)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0,0,100);
        }
        else
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm setting the flag `naviRotate` in another script in two places `true` and `false`.
I want that when the transform is not rotating always face forward. The problem is that the line

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

Is in the Update so it will try to rotate facing all the time in the game. I want it to make it face forward once.

Each time when the transform stop rotating make it face forward once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare private boolean which will assigned equal to your navirotate bool variable at awake method and then assign this boolean equal to your navirotate on every frame in update method. I write this code just now and it worked and you need to do something like this too.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isRotating;
    private bool observer;

    void Awake() {
        observer = isRotating;    
    }

    void Update() {
        if (isRotating) {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 100 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (isRotating != observer) {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        }

        observer = isRotating;
    }

}
```

Comment: A better line of code would be `transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity`, Euler angles are an abstraction built on the quaternion.